# Which Flurry SDK Should I Use With Phonegap

Tags: mobile, cordova, sdk, flurry

I am installing Flurry into a Phonegap application so that I might collect better in app analytics.  I've seen numerous cordova plugins allowing you to use Flurry's iPhone and Android SDKs with Phonegap

e.g. https://github.com/jfpsf/flurry-phonegap-plugin

However Flurry has released a Mobile Web SDK.  I assume the Mobile Web SDK is easier to integrate with a phonegap application, however I'm concerned that it is not as full featured or ill suited for working with phonegap.  Can anyone comment on which SDK should be used in this situation?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posing the question to Flurry's support team I received the following reply:

```
"The Mobile Web SDK tracks devices on the basis of cookies. The native SDK's track it on the basis of device id.

Apart from that, the mobile web SDK doesn't provide metrics like carrier, device and OS metrics. The native SDK provides those.

Crash reporting is not supported on the Mobile Web SDK. The native iOS and Android SDK's provide that."
```

Ergo, the SDKs are not created equally.  One should use the native SDKs whenever they have the opportunity.